# Java Class Path Search Order Issue

Tags: java

I am trying to build and execute a small Java/Selenium application from the Windows 10 command line, without creating a complete Maven project.  I am running Java 17, and running into a Java execution time error:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

I have a simple directory structure:

```
Selenium (containing SeleniumTest1.java)
   |
   - classes (containing all selenium-java-4.16.1 jars)
   |
   - auxClasses (containing failsafe-3.3.2.jar, google-collections-1.0.jar, guava-17.0.jar)
```

I successfully compile with:

```
C:\Selenium>javac -cp .\classes\selenium-api-4.16.1.jar;.\classes\selenium-chrome-driver-4.16.1.jar;.\classes\selenium-chromium-driver-4.16.1.jar;.\classes\selenium-remote-driver-4.16.1.jar;.\classes\selenium-support-4.16.1.jar SeleniumTest1.java
```

Execution fails without some aux classes.  On successive execution attempts, I discovered required jars, which I placed in the auxClasses directory.

Then when I try:

```
C:\Selenium>java -cp .;.\classes\*;.\auxClasses\* SeleniumTest1
```

I get error:

```
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.base.Throwables
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 9 more
```

The required class **com.google.common.base.Throwables** exists in **auxClasses\guava-17.0.jar** as

```
 spals\shaded\com\google\common\base\Throwables
```

To try to solve this, I extracted **guava-17.0.jar** to remove the **spals\shaded** prefix, making **com** the root folder, and put the resulting files in the directory structure as **guava-17.0-extracted**:

```
Selenium (SeleniumTest1.java)
    |
    - classes (all selenium-java-4.16.1 jars)
    |
    - auxClasses (failsafe-3.3.2.jar, google-collections-1.0.jar, guava-17.0.jar)
    |
    - guava-17.0-extracted (files with root folder com rather than spals)
```

I then added **guava-17.0-extracted** to the end of the class path:

```
C:\Selenium>java -cp .;.\classes\*;.\auxClasses\*;.\guava-17.0-extracted SeleniumTest1
```

Since the runtime is looking for **com\google\common\base\Throwables**, and the package path is part of the class name, it should skip **spals\shaded\com\google\common\base\Throwables** in **auxClasses\guava-17.0.jar** and find it in **guava-17.0-extracted**.

However, when I execute, I get:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: spals/shaded/com/google/common/base/Throwables (wrong name: com/google/common/base/Throwables)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:862)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:681)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:639)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:177)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:523)
        ... 7 more
```

If it's now looking for **spals/shaded/com/google/common/base/Throwables**, it should find it in **auxClasses\guava-17.0.jar**, and not be concerned with **guava-17.0-extracted**.

I'm not sure what it's doing.